# Is there a way to manage fragment flow navigation dynamically using something like LiveData observers?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I'm newbie to Android development and I recently started to create a new application.

Consider that you have an application with 2 activities :`MainActivity & TourneeFlowActivity`. Also, you have 3 Fragments (I will call them `StartTourneeFragment, ValidateTourneeFragment and EndingTourneeFragment` for the example).

I've implemented Room and Repository pattern for retrieving local and remote data. Also, I've implemented ViewModels to refresh and manage UI data (LiveData) using observers.

Inside my TourneeFlowActivity, I have a fragmentNavigationImplementation (object class), for my fragment navigation flow (for ex: switch from StartTourneeFragment to ValidateTourneeFragment, using a callback listener in activity).

For now, fragment navigation is only called on user events caughted (such as a click on a button `Next` or `Previous`.

Could it be possible to use observers on object property change to trigger something like a callback which could change fragment dynamically?

Code example is not what I've done, but for illustrating what kind of mechanism I would like to do ...

I hope I'm clear with that.

```php
public class TourneeFlowActivity extends Activity {
      private FragmentNavigationImpl fragmentNavigation;
      private BordereauViewModel bordereauViewModel;
      @Override
      public void onCreate() { 
          /// Some initializations
          this.bordereau = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BordereauViewModel.class);
      }

      @Override
      protected onActivityCreated(){
           this.bordereauViewModel.getCurrentBorderau().observe(this, new Observer<Bordereau>{
                @Override
                public onChanged(@Nullable Bordereau bordereau) {
                // Here my value has been changed so I would start a new fragment dynamically
                    if(bordereau != null && bordereau.getStep() == MyEnum.STEP_TO_ENDING) {

                        if(fragmentNavigation.getCurrentFragment() 
                                    instanceof ValidateTourneeFragment) 
                        {
                            EndingFragment fragment = new EndingFragment();
                            fragmentNavigation.nextFragment(fragment);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
      }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem in just setting the `LiveData` every time the object property changes?

Comment: The problem would be more : is it a good practice to use the object property changed to instantiate and start a New fragment (inside the onChanged method of live data). Because I know that livedata are used to manage ui data but what about instantiate and start New fragment ?

Comment: There is a common and similar use case of what you want to achieve. Many a time, we show loading screen until the data is loaded, after which we pass the data and start a new UI component, in your case: fragment. So it's perfectly ok to start a new fragment on data change.